# Apache httpd mod-auth-form giving error 405

Tags: httpd.conf

I have been trying to setup a new website, and I have now ran into a major problem. When I log in to the page it simply gives me the following error when I enter the correct credentials:

`Method Not Allowed The requested method GET is not allowed for the URL /RestrictedPages/index.html.`

When I enter the wrong credentials it works just as I want it to.

Here is my httpd.conf (The parts that I changed):

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module modules/mod_proxy_hcheck.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so


#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/etc/apacheHttpd/htdocs/RestrictedPages">
SetHandler form-login-handler
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation /loginPage.html
AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation /RestrictedPages/index.html
AuthFormProvider file
AuthType form
AuthName "Reserved Area"
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/
Require valid-user

# This is the login page
ErrorDocument 401 /loginPage.html

# This is the file containing users login data
AuthUserFile /etc/apacheHttpd/auth/.htpasswd

</Directory>

#<Location /auth/logout.html>
#    SetHandler form-logout-handler
#    AuthType form
#    AuthName "Reserved Area"
#    Session On
#    SessionCookieName session path=/
#</Location>
```

Here is the login form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/RestrictedPages/index.html">          
            <p><span>Användarnamn:</span><input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" /></p>
                <p><span>Lösenord:</span><input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" /></p>
                <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></p>
    </form>
```

Could anyone of you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Best Regards

Oskar

PS. If you are missing something from my files, just ask me. This is my first time asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I solved it now...

I figure that the problem was in the form-login-handler, I did the following changes:

```
<Location "/RestrictedPages">
    AuthFormProvider file
    ErrorDocument 401 "/loginPage.html"
    AuthUserFile "/etc/apacheHttpd/auth/.htpasswd"
    AuthType form
    AuthName realm 
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/loginPage.html"
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "/RestrictedPages/index.html"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The changes I made were all according to [this document under the headline "basic configuration"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html).

Thanks anyways,
Oskar